# Is there a way to detect if a UIImage / NSData is animated / a GIF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage, nsdata

Not completely sure how they do it, but with the photo sharing site Imgur, the file extension doesn't seem to matter. Take this GIF: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCOVr.gif if I change `.gif` to `.jpg` it's the same result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hVjg.gif

If I use, say, `NSURLSession` to download the latter link, is there a way to identify the resulting `NSData` (or `UIImage` if I transform it into that) as animated?

Basically, is there a way to check if a downloaded image is animated or not?

Comment: You could try [CGImageSourceGetCount](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageSourceGetCount), check if > 1.

Comment: CGImageSourceGetCount doesn't work, it returns > 1 for PDFs

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say it's because their server is ignoring the extension and serving you http://i.imgur.com/bNHPTot

The content-type returned from HEAD requests for both of the URLs you have provided is "image/gif". You could check for the content-type of your response to determine basic animate functionality, but static gifs will report the same as animated ones. You would have to decode the gif yourself in order to detect multiple frames. There are probably libraries out there to help you with this.

Comment: Library for reference: https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia reckons frames are separated in the gif file by Graphic Control Extensions (2 byte headers 21 F9). You could parse the gif and assume it's animated if there's more than one GCE.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF